# Convert from nvarchar to datetime from a large record table with potentially bad date strings

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, nvarchar

I have a main table called `Cases` that I am inserting data into. I have a alternative table where all of the raw data called `rawTableData` is stored and then sent to the main table.

I have a `nvarchar` column in my `rawTableData`that stores a datetime string in this format

```
2016-04-04-10.50.02.351232
```

I have a column in my `Cases` table that has a datatype of `DATETIME`.

I first tried to find the bad data in this method below

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, nvarcharDateColumn, 103)
FROM rawTableData
WHERE ISDATE(CONVERT(datetime, nvarcharDateColumn, 103)) != 1
```

And I get the error below

> The conversion of nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Then I tried a different approach hoping to find all of the out of range values

```
SELECT nvarcharDateColumn
FROM rawTableData
WHERE ISDATE(nvarcharDateColumn)
```

But that only returns all rows since its nvarchar.

Again, I kept going and tried a different approach

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN ISDATE(nvarcharDateColumn) = 1 THEN nvarcharDateColumn END, 103)
FROM rawTableData
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and any help would be appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: `IsDate()` is notoriously inaccurate, and storing dates as strings doesn't really help.  Since it's saying that it is resulting in an out-of-range value, do you have any dates that are older than `1753-01-01`?

Comment: @Siyual no the range is between 2013-2017, I think some of the dates might be US and UK

Comment: That might be the issue then - if you're storing dates with both formats in the same field, there's no way to figure out which is which (the ISO standard is `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: @Siyual the problem is that I am not completely sure since its my first time working with such large amount of data. I'm just looking to convert the string date into the correct datetime so I can store it in the cases table. I'm pretty sure the format for all of those dates is UTC

Comment: `MM-DD-YYYY` and  `DD-MM-YYYY` is often mixed up.  This could be the problem. If the MM part happen to be 13, then you will get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT nvarchardatecolumn, TRY_CONVERT(date, nvarchardatecolumn)
FROM rawTableData
```

And if you only want to return the invalid dates, use a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT nvarchardatecolumn, TRY_CONVERT(date, nvarchardatecolumn) DateCheck
      FROM rawTableData
     ) A
WHERE DateCheck IS NULL
```

Comment: The problem is that it will return all of them as null because they are nvarchar but I cannot seem to convert it to a datetime

Comment: Nvarchar can convert to date just fine... If it returns `NULL` for all, it means that none of them are in a correct date format.

Comment: you might be on to something, I just checked the columns that have working datetime values and compared to the one I have in column nvarchardatecolumn there is a line where there shouldnt be, looks like that is the issue. 2016-04-04(--->)-(<---)10.50.02351232

Comment: @Archikuus Sounds like that's it. I would expect this format `2016-04-14 10:40:25.02351232` but if it works it works.

Comment: Going to mark your answer as correct as you helped me realize what was wrong. Cheers